# How to restore/add google search to android browser - Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830L

Tags: browser, samsung-galaxy-ace, google-search

I own a **rooted** Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830L. 
My carrier decide it was a good idea to remove Google search from the default android browser replacing it with a absolutely useless search engine they provide (which I hate with the burning passion of a thousand suns). 
If I go into the browser's settings > Select search Engine, I get the carriers engine as the only option.

Is there a way to install google search or restore the browser back to a non carrier customized version?

I already have Opera mini installed but I want to use both so please do not suggest this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are rooted, you could try to replace the Browser app with one from a ["stock" rom](http://androidforums.com/ace-all-things-root/379655-wiki-always-up-date-samsung-galaxy-aces-custom-roms-thread.html) that doesn't have the different search engine. The problem would be if the device is [odexed](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-odex-and-deodex-in-android-complete-guide/), you might not be able to just replace the app. in which case you would have to install a completely different ROM for the device.

Comment: Installing a custom ROM was my next attempt, but I like the idea you suggest about replacing the Browser app with one from the stock ROM, could you elaborate more on that, please?

Comment: i will post more on it later, but basically you will get an APK from somewhere else and put it on the device. as i said though, most stock roms are odexed so you wont be able to just use any apk file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access the [Google Search app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) to install it from the Market? This will allow you to add the Google Search box to your home screen, as many Android devices have it set by default. I'm pretty sure that this should also add it to to the browsers list of search engines for those who want to search from the address bar.

Other than that you'd just need to change your browser's home page, which (assuming your carrier hasn't locked that down) you should be able to change in the browser's settings (open the browser, press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, scroll down to and click on **Set Home Page** and change to http://www.google.com (or your regional version)).